# In the context of probability is $A \in B$ equivalent to $A \subseteq B$?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

In the notes I'm reading through it says the following :
(events being subsets of the sample space)
"Given events A and B,
$A\in B$ means the events in A belong to the set B"

is this supposed to read $A \subseteq B$?

If A and B are events, what exactly does it mean for the events in A to belong to B?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't make sense in exactly the two ways you indicate. It should presumably read $A\subseteq B$ and say "(all of) the *outcomes* in $A$ belong to the set $B$."

Comment: Also, I suspect that this might not be the case here, but it is generally useful to actually post or link to the notes in question if that is possible, rather than quoting them. This way we can be sure we are not taking anything out of context.

Answer (score 0):

A in B and A subset B are not equivalent.
One source of this bad and deceptive terminology comes from topology.
Expressions like open in S and closed in S are used to mean
an open (closed) subset of S.
Thus the notion A in S comes to mean A subset S.
Better, clear verbage is needed such as open within.

Another woefully sloppy use of words is "A is contained in B".
Does it mean A in B or A subset B?
Care needs to be taken when using the word "contain"
to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I would rather say the use of “in” for “element of” is bad terminology (but too entrenched to change).